# Logged_in is not working in woocommerce plugin wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

We was register in My-Account then login successfully

But, then after We was Enter Id, Password Entered in Login Form And after press Submit Button then was not logged in

In my following wordpress site Login is not working.
I am using Woocommerce My-Account

```
Please try Here
http://best10reviews.com/my-account/


ID : kanala.4020@gmail.com
Pass : kanala
```

Please try to login using above id & Password

Answer (score 0):

It clearly says `"Error: A user could not be found with this email address.".` Please check your database if a user exists with this email address.

Comment: Sorry, Please try this ID : kanala.4020@gmail.com Pass : kanala or register your own and then after logout & try to login again

Answer (score 0):

it says user not found so just check in your wp-admin user list if user exist with this email or not. also check his username in admin and try login with user name if any user exist in admin user list

Comment: Sorry, Please try this ID : kanala.4020@gmail.com Pass : kanala or register your own and then after logout & try to login again

Comment: can you check in debug mode? just enable error reporting in wp-config file and then check dispay error help you.

Comment: which wordpress and woocommerce version you used ? can you upgrade it to latest version. also deactivate all other plugin first and then try to login to site will work or not.